# Scrolling in OpenGL ES 1.1

Tags: android, opengl-es, scroll

I'm developing a 2D side-scrolling game.I have a tiled bitmap for background with size 2400x480.How can i scroll this bitmap?

I know that i can do it with following code:

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
draw(bitmap,2400*i,480);
```

So it will scroll bitmap for 240000 pixels.

But i don't want to draw images which stays out of screen(with size 800x480).

How can i render scrolling tile?How can i give velocity to it?(For parallax scrolling after normal scrolling)

Comment: _scrambling through my brain_ You shouldn't [accept answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10179587/1262542) that don't help you. It's OK.

Comment: @StefanHanke Sorry but i accepted because i supposed to understand what you said.Then i tried to code this algorithm but i can't success.That's why i asked again.

Answer (score 0):

The following code does not use two quads, but one quad, and adapts the texture coordinates accordingly. Please note that I stripped all texture handling code. The projection matrix solely contains `glOrthof(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);`. `Quad2D` defines a quad whose tex coords can be animated using `updateTexCoords`:

```
static class Quad2D {
    public Quad2D() {
        /* SNIP create buffers */
        float[] coords = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, };
        mFVertexBuffer.put(coords);
        float[] texs = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, };
        mTexBuffer.put(texs);
        /* SNIP reposition buffer indices */
    }

    public void updateTexCoords(float t) {
        t = t % 1.0f;
        mTexBuffer.put(0, 0.33f+t);
        mTexBuffer.put(2, 0.0f+t);
        mTexBuffer.put(4, 0.33f+t);
        mTexBuffer.put(6, 0.0f+t);
    }

    public void draw(GL10 gl) {
        glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, mFVertexBuffer);
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, mTexBuffer);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    }
    /* SNIP members */
}
```

Now how to call `updateTexCoords`? Inside `onDrawFrame`, put the following code:

```
    long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 3000L;
    float velocity = 1.0f / 3000.0f;
    float offset = time * velocity;
    mQuad.updateTexCoords(offset);
```

Since the texture coordinates go beyond `1.0f`, the texture wrap for the S coordinate must be set to `GL_REPEAT`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok working with shaders, we can have a cleaner and may be more efficient way of doing this.

Create a VBO with a quad covering the whole screen. The witdth and height should be 800 and 480 respectively.

then create your vertex shader as:

```
attribute vec4 vPos;
uniform int shift;
varying mediump vec2 fTexCoord;
void main(void){
   gl_Position = vPos;
   fTexCoord = vec2((vPos.x-shift)/800.0, vPos.y/480.0);//this logic might change slightly based on which quadarnt you choose.
}
```

The fragment shader would be something like:

```
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D texture;    
varying mediump vec2 fTexCoord;
void main(void){
   gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, fTexCoord);
}
```

and you are done.
To scroll just set the uniform value using "glUniformX()" apis.

Comment: @droidmachine:  If your hw is OpenGL ES2.0 compliant, then most probably your fixed function anyway is getting implemented by shaders only.   Making the shaders simple might gain you some performance figures.