# Iterating through lots of objects

Tags: java, performance

I have an `ArrayList` with 40,000 separate objects that can be drawn to the screen. Right now I have to iterate through all of them, and perform a calculation if they are showing on the screen, before I draw them with a `Graphics2D` object.

```
for (GameObject object : gameObjects) {
        if (insideScreenView(object)) {
            object.draw(g2d);
        }
    }
```

This doesn't take too long, but it does take about 2-5 ms. Only about 100 of these objects are showing on the screen at any given time. Meaning that I am running 39,900 iterations that aren't necessary. Is there a better way to do this, given that I **know** most iterations don't have to happen.

**Edit:**
Objects are chosen to be on screen based on if an object's bounding rectangle intersects the screen via `Rectangle`'s `intersects()` method.

Comment: Could you give us more info on how you know what objects to choose and not?

Comment: Only way I can see is to implement a 2nd array that contains the objects drawable on the screen. Maybe in your core game loop after you do something with the object check if `insideScreenView` if so then add it to the drawable array.

Comment: Maybe if you post the insideScreenView code we can see it and see if can be improved. (P.S why insideScreenView is not a method of GameObject?)

Comment: Obviously, this has been widely studied in computer graphics. Search for frustrum culling... It usually requires some acceleration data structure like BVH or kd-tree.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno `insideScreenView()` is a single call to `screenRect.intersects(object.getRect())`. Where `screenRect` is a `Rectangle` that holds the location of the in-game camera. It is implemented as-per this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997006/slick2d-and-jbox2d-how-to-draw?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Can you afford an extra thread to manage half of them?

Comment: @rath probably, how would I go about doing that though?

Comment: You keep the extra thread in stand-by and give it the arraylist. At this point, the thread will start checking the objects by starting at arraylist.size()/2, and that's where the main thread stops at (you can scale that up as much as it makes sense). Your biggest problem though would be lock contention, ie. make sure the threads don't fight over resources. If you haven't worked with threads in the past it's gonna be a bit of an uphill battle to get it right the first time, but if done right it can nearly double (or more) performance at this choke-point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of iterating ALL the game objects, you should iterate only the `viewable objects`.

So, how to do that?

->> **METHOD 1** (slow, but simple) <<-

First, separate your game logic in 2 pieces: `updateView()`, and `draw()`.

- updateView():
  Here, you `calculate` what objects are inside the screen, and add them to a simple `List` (you can choose `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`, each one will have different performance impact, so, benchmark them!).
- draw():
  Here, you iterate over all the objects on the `List` you created before on `updateView`, and `draw` them.

->> **METHOD 2** (fast, but complex) <<-

The basic logic is somewhat like Method 1: you have the viewable objects inside a List, and draw them on `draw()` method. But the difference between these methods is that, on this method, instead of each tick verify what objects are viewable, you `check when the objects move`.

Depending on how your Game Objects are managed, `Method 1 can be faster` (if your Game Objects are moving every time, like `particles`), but for general purposes, `this method is faster`.

So, inside Game Object, you add a boolean called `addedToViewList`. This boolean indicates whether the object `is added to the viewable objects list`, so we don't need to use `list.contains(object)` and iterate over it. Then, every tick, you check if the object is already on the list. If it is, you check if he is viewable or not: if not, you `remove` him from list. If he wasn't on the list, but he is viewable, then you `add` him to list.

Example:

```
public void onMove() {
  if (addedToViewList && !insideScreenView()) {
    this.addedToViewList = false;
    (view list).remove(this);
  }
  else if (!addedToViewList && insideScreenView()) {
    this.addedToViewList = true;
    (view list).add(this);
  }
}
```

Hope I helped you. See ya!

Comment: Usually camera moves all the time in a game. Which makes method 2 not very good idea.

Comment: Yes, as I said, depending on how the Game Objects are managed, method 1 can and WILL be faster.

Comment: Can you explain how to calculate which ones are on the screen. How would this be faster than calculating at every draw?

Comment: The same way you are calculating now. And think with me: what is faster, verify if every of 40.000 objects are on the screen every tick, or calculate if each object are on the screen only when they move?